# Windows 2008 Server R2, Many IP addresses, using specific as 'default'

Tags: ip, windows-server-2008, default-value

I have many IP addresses configured for Windows Server 2008.  I want to use a specific IP address for the 'default'  (say Iexplorer or Chrome was used).

Is this possible, and how can I go about doing this?

The 'default' address listed in Network Properties-> Connection is not being used. I had always 'thought' that would be default, but apparently not.

Comment: is this the only option?  (searched my question in google). http://www.aip.im/2013/01/how-to-set-the-primary-ip-address-of-a-windows-server-2008-r2/

Comment: if that IS the solution, is it OK to use if other IPs have outgoing traffic?

Comment: first comment is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you need to be sure that for the outer world traffic of your web browser originates from particular IP address? Or something else?

If my guess is right it all boils down to routing/default gateway configuration...

If you be more specific about result you want to achieve you may get more precise advise.